# subadditive function of brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $W_t$ be Brownian, and let $g$ be integrable , and odd, and subadditive
$g(x+y)\le g(x)+g(y)$.   How to show that $g(W_t)$ is a supermartingale?
I am not sure how to make use of the subadditive of the function $g$. Can I have some hints please?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $0\leq s\leq t$, the subadditivity gives $g(W_t)\leq g(W_s)+g(W_t-W_s)$.